# Managing updates when loading CSV in Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, updates, insert-update

I'm importing CSV weekly in my Neo4j database, with 90% of data already existing. It's my database update process.

I'm merging data with ids and I put a unique constraints on these to be sure.

Everything is fine from a technical point of view. But from an operational point of view, I have some needs :

1- I have :Org, :Person nodes and :MEMBER_OF relationships, and I need to track any change from week to week. Did he join another Org (the easy part) ? Did he left another one (the tricky part) ?  I want to update the former relationships with an attribute "OBSOLETE" or replace it by a new relationship FORMER_MEMBER_OF to keep a track.

=> How can I do that ?

2- I manually update label and names for display consistency (remove parenthesis with acronyms, add capital letters, ...). When I load the update CSV, name is overwriten with the name in the CSV. I can't "lock" the field with a secondary field as some CSV label and name updates can be legitimate (an org can change its name).

=> How can I review the attribute changes ? Is there a way to preview all the modified node and relationship attributes before accepting the data in database ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question the CSV you're loading contains all of the information for a complete reload of your data, or at least one domain of your data, and you want to track the adds, updates, and deletes that result.

If my assumption is correct then for your first question, you can set a `csv_status` property to something like `deleted` on every node and relationship that may be affected. You'd do this prior to running CSV LOAD. In the ON MATCH of your MERGE statements you can then set `csv_status` to `matched` and in the ON CREATE you can set it to `new`. After the CSV LOAD every node or relationship with a `csv_status` of `deleted` didn't appear in your CSV and you can post-process accordingly.

For you second question, I'd consider holding two versions of the name property in your nodes. The "raw" value loaded from the CSV and the scrubbed or edited value. In the CSV LOAD you would update just the raw name value. As a post processing step you could then compare the raw names against the scrubbed names on all of the :Org nodes with a `csv_status` of `matched` using some type of programmatic match. For example, perhaps compare just the alphas in the two names. If the match fails then the org name may have changed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Interesting proposals. These are nice solutions I'm going to experiment right away !